# Tic Tac Toe program by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in programming. I have an assignment to make a Tic Tac Toe program using html and javascript. I've got a code related to Tic Tac Toe from one website but i couldn't understand the exact behavior of that code. Here's the code i have.

```
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
    document.write('<style>.tictac{')
    document.write('width:50px;height:50px;')
    document.write('}</style>')
}
```

On this code, the tictac is a class selector of button. Could anyone please explain the behavior of this code?.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try to learn a bit more about web development before you try to develop a Tic-Tac-Toe game.

Comment: Being "New" you should stick with Hello World print out codes before getting into more complex programming of games

Comment: That code is not a good example (you don't want to be using `document.write()` and you don't want to be creating style elements from JavaScript). Anyway, all that code does is create a style element with a single CSS class that styles elements that have that class to be 50px by 50px. So really that is the least important part of a Tic-Tac-Toe implementation

Comment: @nnnnnn I would like to add if `document` object is available and `document.getElementById` is not undefined.

Comment: @SagarV - That if condition will always be true - wouldn't you have to go back to the 90s to find a browser that doesn't support `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: yes. It will true for all case even in **IE**. Jjust explained the statement. @nnnnnn

Comment: Thanks for all your quick replies. I got some idea from your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not related to Tic-Tac-Toe. This is general JavaScript code. Not Specific.

All this do is check whether a `document.all` is present and whether `getElementById` function is present or not. Which is true for present World.

`document.all` list all elements and `document.getElementById` is a function which return the element with id that match the argument you pass.
Then write the HTML style code to document.

```
<style>
 .tictac{
       width:50px;
       height:50px;
 }
</style>
```

For your understanding, The snippet is below.

I added a `div` with `class=tictac` and styled it with `background-color` `black`

When you run the snippet, the size of `div` is set to `50x50` .

That is all this code do.

```js
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
  document.write('<style>.tictac{')
  document.write('width:50px;height:50px;')
  document.write('}</style>')
}
```

```css
.tictac{
  background-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tictac">ABCD</div>
```

Comment: Your explanation helps me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: if it is helpful, you can mark it as answer. @SivakumarTN